# Will this Camel Route acknowledge message in exception scenario?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have a Camel route which converts JSON to an object and passes it on to a processor class. Code is below. This ActiveMQ consumer is not acknowledging some messages, causing the topic to get backed up. The code does not explicitly set acknowledgement mode but a breakpoint shows these values -

acknowledgementMode = -1
acknowledgementModeName =  null

What should be changed to ensure acknowledgements are sent on both successful processing and when an exception occurs inside the processor class?

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private String mySubscription;

    private MyProcessor myProcessor;

    public MyRoute(@Value("${my.topic}") String tripSubscription, MyProcessor myProcessor) {
        this.mySubscription = mySubscription;
        this.myProcessor = myProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(mySubscription)
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyDTO.class)
                .bean(myProcessor, "process(${body})")
                .end();
    }
}
```

The processor class -

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyProcessor {

    public void process(MyDTO dto) {

        //code that throws exception

    }

}
```

Comment: camel-jms should use AUTO ack mode by default, and the message is ACK'ed asap when its received (not transaction semantics). What version of Camel and ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: In the code, Camel version is 2.19.5 and ActiveMQ version is 5.15.8 (although the broker I connect to, shows 5.15.2)

Comment: Hello @ClausIbsen.
Thanks for the replay, could you please point me to the code in (https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/main/components/camel-jms) where the ack is sent? I m troubleshooting a case where the message is deleted from the broker (persistent queue) even if the route is configured to "?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE". and no message.acknowledge() is called! (I checked the AcknowledgementMode() is equal to 2).
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out, It's the commitIfNecessary() method, at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer class,  that is called if acknowledgment mode is set to client_acknowladge.

Answer (score 1):

The Camel [JMS component docs at Github](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/main/docs/jms-component.adoc) says that the default acknowledge mode is `AUTO_ ACKNOWLEDGE`.

However, the older [docs at camel.apache.org](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) says the default is `-1` **what corresponds to the value you see**. Either the default was changed in a recent version or the new docs at Github are wrong.

The value `-1` is **somehow invalid** because it is none of [the defined modes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE).

Therefore you could give it a try to **explicitly set `acknowledgementModeName=AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` on your consumer**.

Answer (score 1):

Side note… looks like you’re not setting “tripSubscription” into and instance variable if that was your intent…